# jquery validation errorClass not working properly

Tags: jquery, forms, coding-style, element, validation

What's going on is when you just press "Send" only the message-body textbox is turning red, meaning *errorClass: 'errorField'* was applied to it like it should be, but the other elements do not turn red, like they should.

Also, the focus properly goes to the message-email text input, so perhaps errorClass is properly being applied to this field as well but then when you change the focus to the message-subject field the message-email field should turn red.

Finally, how do I have the errorField class override the focus class?

*Thanks for your help!*

**HTML:**

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/message.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#message-form").validate({
        errorClass: 'errorField',
        errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                       return true;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    blue = focus, green=notFocus, red=error
<div id="message-wrapper">
    <form id="message-form" method="POST" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="70px"><label for="message-email">From:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="message-email" id="message-email" class="message-input required email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="message-subject">Subject:</label>  </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="message-subject" id="message-subject" class="message-input required" minlength="5"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="message-body" style="vertical-align: top">Message:</label>  </td>
                <td><textarea name="message-body" id="message-body" rows="4" cols="40" class="message-input required"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="1" />

        <p><button type="submit">Send</button></p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#message-wrapper{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
input[type="text"], textarea {
    /* background:#F4F4F4; */
    background: green;
    color: white;
    border: solid 2px #DFDFDF;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    /* background:#F2F4F8; */
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    border:solid 2px #333;
    outline: 0;
}
.errorField{
    /* background:#faf6d1; */
    background: red;
    color:black;
    border:solid 1px #333;
}
.message-input{
    width: 341px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selectors are the issue:

- `input[type="text"]` is more specific than `.message-input`, so the background color does not change
- Use `input.message-input:focus` instead of `input[type="text"]:focus` and `input.message-input.errorField:focus` instead of `.errorField`